# не работает элемент <param> в элементе <object> для видео

Tags: html5, tag

здраствуйте.. в моей коде для -а не работает элемент . мой код такой:

```
 <body> 

<object width = "320" height = "240" data= "BMW-M8.mp4" type= "video/mp4"  >
    <param name= "autoplay" value= "true" >
</object>
```

если знаете почему, пожалуста обеснитье...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у вас метке вопроса указано `html5`, то попробуйте вставить при помощи [<video>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video):

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="BMW-M8.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: то есть не подерживается в html5-ом?

Comment: @SamvelGhumashyan В html5 элемент object — способ вставки ресурсов для плагинов. А обычное видео вставляется при помощи элемента video — он поддерживается всеми современными браузерами (иначе, появится строчка "Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.")

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ.